# How to clear drawn line (inside a function) using button in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Already make lines between the points using following code (inside a function).I need to clear that lines using button.

```
var v = 0;

function getLocation(a,b,c,d,e)
 {

   if (v>0)
     {
       var line1:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
           line1.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x00CCFF);
           line1.graphics.moveTo(a,b);
           line1.graphics.lineTo(c,d);
           this.addChild(line1);
     }
   else
     {
      v++;
      var line2:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
          line2.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x00CCFF);
          line2.graphics.moveTo(a,b);
          line2.graphics.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
          this.addChild(line2);
     }
 }
```

Comment: why you create different movieclips, cant you declare var line1:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); outside of function and then clear it with line1.graphics.clear();

Comment: You also don't need to use `MovieClip`, just use `Shape` if all you need is a graphics drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using an array.

```
var v = 0;
var arr: Array = new Array();

function getLocation(a,b,c,d,e)
{
    if (v>0)
    {
        var line1:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            line1.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x00CCFF);
            line1.graphics.moveTo(a,b);
            line1.graphics.lineTo(c,d);
            arr.push(line1);
            this.addChild(line1);
    }
    else
    {
        v++;
        var line2:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            line2.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x00CCFF);
            line2.graphics.moveTo(a,b);
            line2.graphics.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
            arr.push(line2);
            this.addChild(line2);
    }
}

function removeLine(): void
{
    if (arr.length != 0) {
        var mc:MovieClip = arr.pop();
        this.removeChild(mc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be give an instance name to movieclip and then clear it later

```
var v:Number = 0;
function getLocation(a,b,c,d,e)
 {
     //find out previous clip, based on v variable;
    var ch:MovieClip = this.getChildByName("myline"+(v-1)) as MovieClip;
    if(ch)
    {
        ch.graphics.clear(); 
        //even remove it because seems like you dont need it any more
        this.removeChild(ch);
    }

    var line:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    line.name = "myline"+v;//give it a name, help in finding later
    line.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x00CCFF);
    line.graphics.moveTo(a,b);
    if (v>0)
    {
        line.graphics.lineTo(c,d);
    }
    else
    {
        v++;
        line.graphics.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
     }
    this.addChild(line);
 }
```

I would suggest you to use following unless you have special requirement

```
var v:Number = 0;
var line:MovieClip;
function getLocation(a,b,c,d,e)
{
    if(line==null)
    {
        line = new MovieClip;
        addChild(line);
    }
    else
    {
        line.graphics.clear();
    }
    line.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x00CCFF);
    line.graphics.moveTo(a,b);
    if (v>0)
    {
        line.graphics.lineTo(c,d);
    }
    else
    {
        v++;
        line.graphics.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
     }
 }
 //It can be cleared from here as well
 function onButtonClickHandler(e:MouseEvent)
 {
    if(line)
    {
        line.graphics.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all your lines in a container:

```
var lines:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(lines);

function getLocation(a, b, c, d) {
    // ...
    lines.addChild(line);
}
```

Then to remove them use:

```
lines.removeChildren();
```